# Simulate pressing a button in swift

Tags: swift

I have the following method

```
@IBAction func clearDisplay(sender: UIButton)
```

and I want to overload this method so that I can clear the display if some conditions are satisfied in my code. So

```
func clearDisplay()
```

My idea is to simply simulate pressing the clearDisplay button but am not sure how to do that. Does this sound like a good idea? How would I simulate pressing the button?

Comment: Don't "simulate" anything. You already _have_ a `func clearDisplay(sender:UIButton)` which does what you want. Just call it.

Comment: Sometimes things that are obvious to one are not as obvious to another. Duncan's modification to the method signature below was what I needed.

Comment: Actually what I do is write `@IBAction func clearDisplay(sender: UIButton!)`, thus making it legal to pass `nil` if we perform the call manually. Or, alternatively, if you do not need the button for anything in the method, just declare it as  `@IBAction func clearDisplay()` - perfectly legal not to capture the sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matt says, just call the IBAction method directly. You should probably change the object type of sender to AnyObject, and then use

```
clearDisplay(self)
```

Which will pass in the view controller as the sender.

In your clearDisplay method, if you have code that does something with the button, check it's type first to make sure it really is a button.

Comment: Thank you. This what was missing. I needed to change UIButton to AnyObject so I can call it with self as the argument. Thank you.

Comment: Note that you can also set up IBActions to not take any parameters at all. Sometimes that's the cleanest solution.

Comment: @DuncanC Snap! Just said the same thing in a comment above. :))